# Find sub-documents using $in with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find

My task is to find individual authors(`comments.user_id`) comment on the article (`_id`)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56479d9c8510369a4ecea3a9"),
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "text" : "222",
            "user_id" : ObjectId("563f2db0e2bf6c431b297d45"),
        }, 
        {
            "text" : "333",
            "user_id" : ObjectId("563f2db0e2bf6c431b297d45"),
        }, 
        {
            "text" : "444",
            "user_id" : ObjectId("563f2db0e2bf6c431b297d45"),
        }, 
        {
            "text" : "55555",
            "user_id" : ObjectId("563e3337e2bf6c431b297d41"),
        }, 
        {
            "text" : "00000",
            "user_id" : ObjectId("563f7c0a8db7963420cd5732"),
        }, 
        {
            "text" : "00001",
            "user_id" : ObjectId("563f7c0a8db7963420cd5732"),
        }
    ]
}
```

My query looks as follows

```
db.getCollection('messages').find({
  '_id': ObjectId("56479d9c8510369a4ecea3a9"),
  'comments.user_id': {$in : [
    ObjectId("563e3337e2bf6c431b297d41"),
    ObjectId("563f7c0a8db7963420cd5732")
  ]}
})
```

It returns all comments. Please help to understand why it happens.

Expected Result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56479d9c8510369a4ecea3a9"),
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "text" : "55555",
            "user_id" : ObjectId("563e3337e2bf6c431b297d41"),
        }, 
        {
            "text" : "00000",
            "user_id" : ObjectId("563f7c0a8db7963420cd5732"),
        }, 
        {
            "text" : "00001",
            "user_id" : ObjectId("563f7c0a8db7963420cd5732"),
        }
    ]
}
```

### update query (hopelessness)

```
db.getCollection('messages').find(
    {'_id': ObjectId("56479d9c8510369a4ecea3a9")},
    {'comments.user_id': {$in:  ["563f2db0e2bf6c431b297d45", "563e3337e2bf6c431b297d41"]}},
    {'comments.user_id': {$elemMatch: {$in:  ["563f2db0e2bf6c431b297d45", "563e3337e2bf6c431b297d41"]}}}
     )


db.getCollection('messages').find(
    {'_id': ObjectId("56479d9c8510369a4ecea3a9")},
     {comments: {$elemMatch: {'user_id': {$in : [ObjectId("563f2db0e2bf6c431b297d45"), ObjectId("563f7c0a8db7963420cd5732")]}}}}  
    )
```

I return only 1 record, and I have all the records from these authors

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful. Repeat: Read the documentation **before** asking a question. Since the document matches, it is returned. Use `elemMatch` and the positional `$`operator for projection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply `db.getCollection('messages').find(
        {
            '_id': ObjectId("564680c59bfd4a0a49745282"),
             'comments.user_id': {$elemMatch: {$in:  ["563e3337e2bf6c431b297d41", "563f2db0e2bf6c431b297d45"]}}
         })`  try to realize what you have written, it is still not returns

Comment: I have just made your code more readable – since it is your question, I did not change anything, of course. Please read the links I gave you and [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33712465/edit)  accordingly. That is: provide sample documents and an expected output.

Comment: I'm sorry I have not yet learned to respond nicely

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24032549/1259510) to a similar question.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thanks, I did not get the desired results. the solution does not work $in and return only 1 sub document

Comment: @Alex Can you edit your question to include what you tried?

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks! updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've seen, the `$` and `$elemMatch` projection operators only include the *first* matching element.

To include multiple, filtered array elements in your projection of the `comment` array, your can use `aggregate` with the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact) operator instead of `find`:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
    {$match: {
        '_id': ObjectId("56479d9c8510369a4ecea3a9"),
        'comments.user_id': {$in : [
            ObjectId("563e3337e2bf6c431b297d41"),
            ObjectId("563f7c0a8db7963420cd5732")
        ]},
    }},
    {$redact: {
        $cond: {
            if: {
                $or: [
                    {$eq: ['$user_id', ObjectId("563e3337e2bf6c431b297d41")]},
                    {$eq: ['$user_id', ObjectId("563f7c0a8db7963420cd5732")]},
                    {$not: '$user_id'}
                ]
            },
            then: '$$DESCEND',
            else: '$$PRUNE'
        }
    }}
])
```

`$redact` iterates over each doc like a tree, keeping or trimming the fields of each doc as it's `$cond` expression dictates.

It gets a bit tricky to wrap your head around `$redact`, but it's basically saying that if the level's `user_id` field matches either of the two ObjectIds in your `$in`, or it's not present (i.e. as it is in the top level of the doc), include the data, otherwise remove it.

Comment: Thank you for writing the decision, but I can not understand why I can not refer to the property `comments`, handling writes `undifined`

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @JohnyyHK, Sorry for my English, I mean that I can not appeal to data `comments`, return `undifined` `console.log(message[0].comments);` -->`undifined`

Comment: @JohnyyHk i remove `'comments.user_id': {$in: [ObjectId("563e3337e2bf6c431b297d41"), ObjectId("563f7c0a8db7963420cd5732")]}` in $match, and all was well! thank you, on no other choice in the mangoDB?

Comment: @Alex The [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter) array aggregation operator will make this easier in 3.2.

Comment: @JohnyyHk,Thank you then I will wait for 3.2